# webpack loader module.exports strange behaviour

Tags: webpack, handlebars.js

I'm writing a custom webpack loader.

It's converts handlebars into handlebar templates, but I'm running into a strange issue when exporting an object instead of a function.

essentially **this works fine:**

```
'module.exports = (Handlebars).template(' + source + ');'
```

**this fails**: with error(`The partial foo could not be compiled when running in runtime-only mode`):

```
'module.exports.compile = (Handlebars).template(' + source + ');'
```

How is it any different?

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports = () => {
  compile: handlebars.template(templateSpec),
  attributes: myFrontMatterData
}
```

This cannot work, because it's not valid JavaScript and you should get a  `SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`. When you use curly brackets, the arrow function has a regular block [Function body](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body), it's not implicitly returning an object, but is just like a regular function. With a block body the correct function would be:

```
module.exports = () => {
  return {
    compile: handlebars.template(templateSpec),
    attributes: myFrontMatterData
  }
}
```

You can still use object literals as implicit returns, but because curly brackets are reserved to signalise blocks, you need to wrap the object literal in parentheses (see also [Returning object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Returning_object_literals)):

```
module.exports = () => ({
  compile: handlebars.template(templateSpec),
  attributes: myFrontMatterData
})
```

Comment: Hey Michael thanks for the info, I tried wrapping in parentheses but it's still not giving the same behaviour as when exporting a single function. Basically running the compilation when from object method it throws `ERROR in Error: The partial myPartial could not be compiled when running in runtime-only mode` but when running it as single function it renders fine. So it's exporting fine but for some reason the function invokes with a different result when it's exported as a method of and object. Wondering if it's an edge case with the webpack module api or if there is some other possibility?

Answer (score 0):

Anyone passing by I solved by doing this.

```
var slug = template ?
        'var Handlebars = require(' + JSON.stringify(runtimePath) + ');\n'
        + 'function __default(obj) { return obj && (obj.__esModule ? obj["default"] : obj); }\n'
        + 'var fn = Handlebars.template(' + template + ');\n'
        + 'fn.attributes = ' + JSON.stringify(source.attributes) + ';\n'
        + 'module.exports = fn;' :
        'module.exports = function(){return "";};';
```